# Background Image that fits the android studio project

Tags: java, android

When i applied an image to emulator on android studio, it gives an image without covering borders. Screen shot of this problem is as under, but what i get is to completely fill the emulator with my image.

[image]

XML code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XML` looks like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:paddingTop="16dp"
   android:paddingBottom="16dp"" >
```

So the thing you've to do is remove the `paddings` from your XML, and if you have put the image correctly it will fit on your screen :)

### EDIT1

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:background="@drawable/background_image"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

### EDIT2

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

### EDIT3

Use this image instead : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULJpj.jpg

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73774/discussion-on-answer-by-skizo-background-image-that-fits-the-android-studio-proj).